# Spark runs out of memory when grouping by key

Tags: scala, amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I am attempting to perform a simple transformation of common crawl data using Spark host on an EC2 using [this guide](http://spark-summit.org/2013/exercises/launching-a-bdas-cluster-on-ec2.html), my code looks like this:

```
package ccminer

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

object ccminer {
  val english = "english|en|eng"
  val spanish = "es|esp|spa|spanish|espanol"
  val turkish = "turkish|tr|tur|turc"
  val greek = "greek|el|ell"
  val italian = "italian|it|ita|italien"
  val all = (english :: spanish :: turkish :: greek :: italian :: Nil).mkString("|")

  def langIndep(s: String) = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll(all, "*")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if (args.length != 3) {
      System.err.println("Bad command line")
      System.exit(-1)
    }

    val cluster = "spark://???"
    val sc = new SparkContext(cluster, "Common Crawl Miner",
      System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), Seq("/root/spark/ccminer/target/scala-2.10/cc-miner_2.10-1.0.jar"))

    sc.sequenceFile[String, String](args(0)).map {
      case (k, v) => (langIndep(k), v)
    }
    .groupByKey(args(2).toInt)
    .filter {
      case (_, vs) => vs.size > 1
    }
    .saveAsTextFile(args(1))
  }
}
```

And I am running it with the command as follows:

```
sbt/sbt "run-main ccminer.ccminer s3n://aws-publicdatasets/common-crawl/parse-output/segment/1341690165636/textData-* s3n://parallelcorpus/out/ 2000"
```

But very quickly it fails with errors as follows

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.ning.compress.BufferRecycler.allocEncodingBuffer(BufferRecycler.java:59)
at com.ning.compress.lzf.ChunkEncoder.<init>(ChunkEncoder.java:93)
at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkEncoder.<init>(UnsafeChunkEncoder.java:40)
at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkEncoderLE.<init>(UnsafeChunkEncoderLE.java:13)
at com.ning.compress.lzf.impl.UnsafeChunkEncoders.createEncoder(UnsafeChunkEncoders.java:31)
at com.ning.compress.lzf.util.ChunkEncoderFactory.optimalInstance(ChunkEncoderFactory.java:44)
at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFOutputStream.<init>(LZFOutputStream.java:61)
at org.apache.spark.io.LZFCompressionCodec.compressedOutputStream(CompressionCodec.scala:60)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.wrapForCompression(BlockManager.scala:803)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$5.apply(BlockManager.scala:471)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$5.apply(BlockManager.scala:471)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(BlockObjectWriter.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(BlockObjectWriter.scala:174)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask$$anonfun$runTask$1.apply(ShuffleMapTask.scala:164)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask$$anonfun$runTask$1.apply(ShuffleMapTask.scala:161)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

So my basic question is, what is necessary to write a Spark task that can group by key with an almost unlimited amount of input without running out of memory?

Comment: What size instance are you running?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138751/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space/22742982#22742982

Answer (score 16):

The most common cause of java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exceptions in shuffle tasks (such as groupByKey, reduceByKey, etc.) is low level of [parallelism](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#level-of-parallelism).

You can increase default value by setting **spark.default.parallelism** property in [configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

Comment: Also coalescing to too few partitions can cause this.

Comment: @jbrown [has a point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961251/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-acquire-100-bytes-of-memory-got-0)!

Comment: Notice that [reduceByKey() is indeed appearing to suffer from the same errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156275/spark-scalability-what-am-i-doing-wrong).

Answer (score 6):

So this says that you have run out of allocated **heap space** of JVM. You may increase heap size but still this is limited by system capabilities (Cannot exceed the amount of physical RAM).

On the other hand as explained by **homutov** this happens in large collecting operations. For example groupByKey, reduceByKey, cartisien + mapToPair . These operations will collect the RDD data into one place making JVM to run out of **heap space**.

What can you do?

With my experience, when a cluster/system have limited resources, you can use use [Spark tuning guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html). **spark.default.parallelism** can be increased till you can accompany task into your cluster/system  [I once ran a KNN implementation for 14000 instance, 1024 feature dataset on my laptop's virtual machine by tweaking parallelism ].

```
Command line flag :   --conf spark.default.parallelism=4   ; 4 is the parallelism value
```

Remember, you need to **TUNE** these features to most effective and fail avoidance (running out of heap) setting to get best results out of Spark.

**Additionally**

Remember to use use **primitive** datatypes instead of **wrappers** . And use **Arrays** instead of **collections**.

```
 ex :  List<Integers> vs int[] ; int[] is better than List
```

In Spark arrays can save many valuable space and improve performance.

Also use **BroadCast** variables instead of Cartesian product or any large combination task.

Comment: good introduction about when, how and why to broadcast can be found https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-broadcast.html

Comment: Typo: spark.default.parallelism not spark.defualt.parallelism