# Determining optimal number of Spark partitions based on workers, cores and DataFrame size

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, distributed-computing, partitioning, bigdata

There are several similar-yet-different concepts in Spark-land surrounding how work gets farmed out to different nodes and executed concurrently. Specifically, there is:

- The Spark Driver node (`sparkDriverCount`)
- The number of worker nodes available to a Spark cluster (`numWorkerNodes`)
- The number of Spark executors (`numExecutors`)
- The DataFrame being operated on by all workers/executors, concurrently (`dataFrame`)
- The number of rows in the `dataFrame` (`numDFRows`)
- The number of partitions on the `dataFrame` (`numPartitions`)
- And finally, the number of CPU cores available on each worker nodes (`numCpuCoresPerWorker`)

I *believe* that all Spark clusters have *one-and-only-one* Spark Driver, and then 0+ worker nodes. If I'm wrong about that, please begin by correcting me! Assuming I'm more or less correct about that, let's lock in a few variables here. Let's say we have a Spark cluster with 1 Driver and 4 Worker nodes, and each Worker Node has 4 CPU cores on it (so a total of 16 CPU cores). So the "given" here is:

```
sparkDriverCount = 1
numWorkerNodes = 4
numCpuCores = numWorkerNodes * numCpuCoresPerWorker = 4 * 4 = 16
```

Given that as the setup, I'm wondering how to determine a few things. Specifically:

- What is the relationship between `numWorkerNodes` and `numExecutors`? Is there some known/generally-accepted ratio of workers to executors? Is there a way to determine `numExecutors` given `numWorkerNodes` (or any other inputs)?
- Is there a known/generally-accepted/optimal ratio of `numDFRows` to `numPartitions`? How does one calculate the 'optimal' number of partitions based on the size of the `dataFrame`?
- I've heard from other engineers that a general 'rule of thumb' is: `numPartitions = numWorkerNodes * numCpuCoresPerWorker`, any truth to that? In other words, it prescribes that one should have 1 partition per CPU core.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, a [spark](/questions/tagged/spark) application has [one and only Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061114/creating-spark-tasks-from-within-tasks-map-functions-on-the-same-application).

> What is the relationship between `numWorkerNodes` and `numExecutors`?

A worker can host multiple executors, you can think of it like the worker to be the machine/node of your cluster and the executor to be a process (executing in a core) that runs on that worker.

So `numWorkerNodes <= numExecutors'.

> Is there any ration for them?

Personally, having worked in a fake cluster, where my laptop was the Driver and a virtual machine in the very same laptop was the worker, *and* in an industrial cluster of >10k nodes, I didn't need to care about that, since it seems that [spark](/questions/tagged/spark) takes care of that.

I just use:

```
--num-executors 64
```

when I launch/submit my script and [spark](/questions/tagged/spark) knows, I guess, how many workers it needs to summon (of course, by taking into account other parameters as well, and the nature of the machines).

Thus, personally, I don't know any such ratio.

---

> Is there a known/generally-accepted/optimal ratio of `numDFRows` to `numPartitions`?

I am not aware of one, but as a rule of thumb you could rely on the product of #executors by #executor.cores, and then multiply that by 3 or 4. Of course this is a *heuristic*. In [pyspark](/questions/tagged/pyspark) it would look like this:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName = "smeeb-App")
total_cores = int(sc._conf.get('spark.executor.instances')) * int(sc._conf.get('spark.executor.cores'))
dataset = sc.textFile(input_path, total_cores * 3)
```

> How does one calculate the 'optimal' number of partitions based on the size of the `DataFrame`?

That's a great question. Of course its hard to answer and it depends on your data, cluster, etc., but as discussed [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/memoryoverhead-issue-in-spark/) with myself.

Too few partitions and you will have enormous chunks of data, especially when you are dealing with [bigdata](/questions/tagged/bigdata), thus putting your application in memory stress.

Too many partitions and you will have your [hdfs](/questions/tagged/hdfs) taking much pressure, since all the metadata that has to be generated from the [hdfs](/questions/tagged/hdfs) increases significantly as the number of partitions increase (since it maintains temp files, etc.). <sup>*</sup>

So what you want is too find a *sweet spot* for the number of partitions, which is one of the parts of *fine tuning your application*. :)

> 'rule of thumb' is: `numPartitions = numWorkerNodes * numCpuCoresPerWorker`, is it true?

Ah, I was writing the heuristic above before seeing this. So this is already answered, but take into account the difference of a *worker* and an *executor*.

---

<sup>*</sup> I just failed for this today: [Prepare my bigdata with Spark via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401690/prepare-my-bigdata-with-spark-via-python), when using too many partitions caused [Active tasks is a negative number in Spark UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964007/active-tasks-is-a-negative-number-spark-ui).

Comment: If `numPartitions` is determined only by `numWorkerNodes ` and `numCpuCoresPerWorker `, then it is irrelevant to `numDFRows `, which means partition size is large if the input dataset is large. which will eventually cause OOM issue. isn't it?

Comment: @fuyi makes a good point. Large datasets will cause OOM for my data if i follow that numPartitions rule of thumb. Anyone have an alternative suggestion?