# Spark repartition performance when converting rdd to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala/spark world and have recently started working on a task where it reads some data, processes it and saves it on S3. I have read several topics/questions on stackoverflow regarding repartition/coalesce performance and optimal number of partitions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381041/determining-optimal-number-of-spark-partitions-based-on-workers-cores-and-dataf)). Assuming that I have the right number of paritions, my questions is, would it be a good idea to repartition a rdd while converting it to dataframe? Here is how my code looks like at the moment:

```
val dataRdd = dataDf.rdd.repartition(partitions)
      .map(x => ThreadedConcurrentContext.executeAsync(myFunction(x)))
      .mapPartitions( it => ThreadedConcurrentContext.awaitSliding(it = it, batchSize = asyncThreadsPerTask, timeout = Duration(3600000, "millis")))

val finalDf = dataRdd
      .filter(tpl => tpl._3 != "ERROR")
      .toDF()
```

Here is what I'm planning to do (repartition data after filter):

```
val finalDf = dataRdd
          .filter(tpl => tpl._3 != "ERROR")
          .repartition(partitions)
          .toDF()
```

My questions is, would it be a good idea to do so? is there a performance gain here?

**Note1:** Filter usually removes 10% of original data.

**Note2:** Here is the first part of spark-submit command that I use to run the above code:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 2G --driver-cores 4 --driver-memory 2G
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem depends on the size of your `dataRdd`, number of partitions, `executor-cores` and processing power of your HDFS cluster.

With this in mind, you should run some tests on your cluster with different values of `partitions` and removing `repartition` altogether to fine tune it and find an accurate answer.

Example - if you specify `partitions=8` and `executor-cores=4` then you will be fully utilizing all your cores, however if the size of your `dataRdd` is only 1GB, then there is no advantage in repartitioning because it triggers `shuffle` which incurs performance impact. In addition to that if the processing power of your HDFS cluster is low or it is under a heavy load then there is an additional performance overhead due to that.

If you do have sufficient resources available on your HDFS cluster and you have a big (say over 100GB) `dataRDD` then a `repartition` should help in improving performance with config values in the example above.