# Spark Container & Executor OOMs during `reduceByKey`

Tags: apache-spark, memory-management, pyspark, emr

I'm running a Spark job on Amazon's EMR in client mode with YARN, using pyspark, to process data from two input files (totaling 200 GB) in size.

The job joins the data together (using `reduceByKey`), does some maps and filters, and saves it to S3 in Parquet format. While the job uses Dataframes for saving, all of our actual transformations and actions are performed on RDDs.

Note, I've included a detailed rundown of my current configurations and values with which I've experimented already after the "Failures" section.

### Code

The code relevant to the failures we're seeing takes place in the `reduceByKey` step. I've included a few lines of context to show one prior map function and the save operations which actually trigger the `reduceByKey` on the RDD:

```
    # Populate UC Property Type
united_rdd = united_rdd.map(converter.convert_uc_property_type(uc_property_type_mappings))

# Reduce by listingIdSha
united_rdd = united_rdd.reduceByKey(converter.merge_listings)

# Filter by each geoId and write the output to storage
schema = convert_struct(ListingRevision)
for geo in GEO_NORMALIZATION_ENABLED_GEOS:
  regional_rdd = (united_rdd.filter(lambda (id_sha, (listing_revision, geo_id)): geo_id == geo)
                            .map(lambda (id_sha, (listing_revision, geo_id)):
                                 listing_revision))
  regional_df = regional_rdd.map(lambda obj: thrift_to_row(obj, schema)).toDF(schema)
  # Write to Disk/S3
  regional_df.write.format(output_format).mode("overwrite").save(os.path.join(output_dir, geo))
  # Write to Mongo
  (regional_df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
                    .option("spark.mongodb.output.uri", mongo_uri)
                    .option("collection",
                            "{}_{}".format(geo, config.MONGO_OUTPUT_COLLECTION_SUFFIX))
                    .mode("overwrite").save())
```

### Failures

The described job fails due to executors running out of physical memory. Multiple executors experience this failure, but here's one example printed in the EMR step's stderr as well as displayed in the Spark History server UI:

```
 Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2787 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times,
 most recent failure: Lost task 2787.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 5792, ip-10-0-10-197.ec2.internal): 
 ExecutorLostFailure (executor 47 exited caused by one of the running tasks) 
 Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 20.0 GB of 20 GB physical memory used. 
 Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
 Driver stacktrace:
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1890)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1923)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
   ... 29 more
```

After discovering this, I dug deeper into the individual node's YARN and container logs and found the YARN log message with the physical memory usage spike and a `java.lang.OutOfMemory` exception in the container logs (included in order described below).

Java `OutOfMemory` Error from Container Logs:

```
17/03/28 21:41:44 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from ip-10-0-10-70.ec2.internal/10.0.10.70:7337
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
  at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:693)
  at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
  at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
  at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:645)
  at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:228)
  at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:212)
  at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:132)
  at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:271)
  at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:155)
  at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:146)
  at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:107)
  at io.netty.channel.AdaptiveRecvByteBufAllocator$HandleImpl.allocate(AdaptiveRecvByteBufAllocator.java:104)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:117)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

YARN's Recognition of Extreme Physical Memory Usage:

```
2017-03-28 21:42:48,986 INFO   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl (Container Monitor): Memory usage of ProcessTree 6310 for container-id container_1490736006967_0001_01_000015: 20.3 GB of 20 GB physical memory used; 24.9 GB of 100 GB virtual memory used
```

In summary, I'm seemingly running out of memory during a shuffle despite allocating over half of my executor's memory to off-heap space and experimenting with a wide range of executor memory settings and cores. Am I missing anything else I can try? Based on a few other helpful posts I've read ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156275/spark-scalability-what-am-i-doing-wrong/39519756#39519756)), these are the most common culprits for physical memory issues. Is it possible data skew could lead to this? I have experimented with measuring partition distribution for smaller subsets of the data and it looked normal, but am unable to do so with all the data for this job since it never finishes.

### Configuration

EMR Spark Submit Command:

```
spark-submit \
   --deploy-mode client /home/hadoop/src/python/uc_spark/data_sources/realtytrac/assr_hist_extractor.py \
   --dataset_settings development \
   --mongo_uri <Internal Mongo URI> \
   --aws_access_key_id <S3 Access Key> \
   --aws_secret_key <S3 Secret Key> \
   --listing_normalization_server <Internal EC2 Address>:9502
```

Relevant Spark Environment Configurations:
`spark.executor.memory` - 8 GB (Out of 20 GB of available memory per executor.)
`spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` - 12 GB
`spark.executor.cores` - 1 (Lowest I've tried in the hope that it would work.)
`spark.default.parallelism` - 1024 (Automatically configured based on other parameters. I've tried 4099 to no avail.)

I'm running with 64 `m3.2xlarge` machines, totaling 1.41 TB of memory.

NOTE: I've experimented with wide ranging values for all memory parameters except driver memory had no luck.

### Update 1

I refactored my code to use Dataframe's `join` instead of RDD's `union` to combine the two input files. Once I did this, I made two important discoveries:

A `rightOuter` join, as opposed to our default `leftOuter` join, reduces our output size but fixes the problem. Given this, I'm fairly certain we have a small subset of skewed data excluded by the `rightOuter` join. Unfortunately, I need to do more investigation to see whether the lost data matters; we're still exploring.

Using Dataframes caused a clearer failure earlier in the process:

```
FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(80, ip-10-0-10-145.ec2.internal, 7337), shuffleId=2, mapId=35, reduceId=435, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Too large frame: 3095111448
  at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:357)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:332)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:54)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
  at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext(SerDeUtil.scala:117)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
  at org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(SerDeUtil.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:504)
  at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:328)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1877)
  at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:269)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too large frame: 3095111448
  at org.spark_project.guava.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:119)
  at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.decodeNext(TransportFrameDecoder.java:133)
  at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:81)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
  at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
  at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
  at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
  at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

)
```

We're failing during a shuffle due to a single partition fetching too much data, a 3 GB "frame".

I'll spend the rest of the day exploring how to de-skew our data and whether we can do a `leftOuter` join.

Comment: m3.2xlarge  has 30GB memory available acc to amazon docs.., any particular reason you are seeing only 20GB?

Comment: @zero323 Good guess, but no it's just a regular for-loop that takes all the values for a given key (which is a SHA-1 sum of an address) and merges them into one final value.

Comment: @Pushkr That's a good point. I based my tweaked memory values on the original amount EMR allocated us when we used the `dynamicAllocation` defaults, but I can definitely try increasing the numbers. At the same time, I'm becoming more convinced that increasing memory either won't solve the problem or is an undesirable workaround. I'm modifying a working version of this pipeline to group by a different ID field and that change alone causes these issues, so I'm thinking more and more that skew or certain incredibly large records are the problem.

Comment: @Pushkr Just tried 17 GB of `memoryOverhead` and 8 GB of `executor.memory` and got the following error:  

`py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required executor memory (8192+17408 MB) is above the max threshold (23040 MB) of this cluster! Please check the values of 'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or 'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.`  

So YARN must reserve those 7 GB.

Comment: Thank for checking that. One thing I can think of is, python does memory management off heap and error is showing need more `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` which is `amount of off-heap memory to be allocated` , this sort of gives indication that py operations are intensive may be? how hard for you to test same logic in scala?

Comment: To my dismay, we don't have a working Scala setup. The `memoryOverhead` suggestion is useful except that no matter how much `memoryOverhead` I allocate (I tried 18 GB with 2 GB of executor memory at one point) the job still fails.

Comment: To follow up, @Pushkr, today I've discovered that the failure's happening on one or a few executors, seemingly due to the same exact set of operations. This leads me to believe that we have pathologically skewed data or certain keys with enough records to OOM an executor. Given this, I'm exploring two options:
1. Use a custom partition function (testing this now).
2. Save an intermediate output pre-`reduceByKey` and run some Spark SQL on that output to detect skew. I'd like to detect skew in the app itself, but I'm not aware of a way to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone discovers this, the problem turned out to result from data skew. I discovered this by switching our initial combining of the two input files to use a Dataframe join rather than an RDD union. This resulted in a more understandable error which showed that our shuffle failed trying to retrieve data. To solve this, I partitioned our data around an evenly distributed key and then everything worked.