# Spark Join Failing without Broadcast

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Experts, i am facing a weird problem where my PySpark join of 2 dataframes is failing if i don't use broadcast. I am using Spark 1.6 with Python 2.17

My Join condition is very simple and the volumes are also minimal (in KB). This is generic code and all these names in below expressions are defined as variables containing exact values and working for many other files.

```
   DF = src.withColumnRenamed(srcCol, lkpCol)\
        .join(broadcast(lkpDF), lkpCol, 'left')\
        .filter(isnull(lkpDF[uniqueID])).coalesce(1)
```

This piece of code is running fine as long as i am broadcasting my lookup Dataframe. The moment i remove it, i am facing below error-

```
19/06/21 13:58:59 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 43.0 (TID 1532, svr-m03wn05.c24.hadoop.com, executor 3): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 228 bytes of memory, got 0
        at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocatePage(MemoryConsumer.java:120)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.acquireNewPageIfNecessary(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:332)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.insertRecord(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:347)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.insertRow(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:168)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Sort$$anonfun$1.apply(Sort.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$21.apply(RDD.scala:728)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoalescedRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(CoalescedRDD.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.CoalescedRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(CoalescedRDD.scala:95)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$2$$anon$1.hasNext(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:140)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:292)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

19/06/21 13:59:00 WARN server.TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from svr-m03wn05.c24.hadoop.com/15.546.349.115:45076
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:242)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
19/06/21 13:59:00 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container marked as failed: container_e68_1561070366427_23261_01_000004 on host: svr-m03wn05.c24.hadoop.com. Exit status: 52. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e68_1561070366427_23261_01_000004
Exit code: 52
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=52:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:604)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:507)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:789)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Shell output: main : command provided 1
main : run as user is userabc
main : requested yarn user is userabc
Writing to tmp file /data/1/yarn/nm/nmPrivate/application_1561070366427_23261/container_e68_1561070366427_23261_01_000004/container_e68_1561070366427_23261_01_000004.pid.tmp


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 52

19/06/21 13:59:00 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 3 on svr-m03wn05.c24.hadoop.com: Container marked as failed: container_e68_1561070366427_23261_01_000004 on host: svr-m03wn05.c24.hadoop.com. Exit status: 52. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e68_1561070366427_23261_01_000004
Exit code: 52
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=52:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:604)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:507)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:789)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:399)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Shell output: main : command provided 1
main : run as user is userabc
main : requested yarn user is userabc
Writing to tmp file /data/1/yarn/nm/nmPrivate/application_1561070366427_23261/container_e68_1561070366427_23261_01_000004/container_e68_1561070366427_23261_01_000004.pid.tmp
```

Comment: My spark-submit is run with config - "spark-submit --conf spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max='1024m' --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=5 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=10 --executor-memory 4G --driver-memory 2G"

Comment: you do DF.explainplan and paste the result with or without broadcast hint. i think its using sort merge join with out broadcast hash join

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961251/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-acquire-100-bytes-of-memory-got-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 100 bytes of memory, got 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961251/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-acquire-100-bytes-of-memory-got-0)

Comment: Hi Ram, thanks a lot for the pointers! the problem actually was with the coalesce()., thanks Again!