# Spark raises OutOfMemoryError

Tags: python, apache-spark

When I run my spark python code as below:

```
import pyspark
conf = (pyspark.SparkConf()
     .setMaster("local")
     .setAppName("My app")
     .set("spark.executor.memory", "512m"))
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf = conf)        #start the conf
data =sc.textFile('/Users/tsangbosco/Downloads/transactions')
data = data.flatMap(lambda x:x.split()).take(all)
```

The file is about 20G and my computer have 8G ram, when I run the program in standalone mode, it raises the OutOfMemoryError:

```
Exception in thread "Local computation of job 12" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:112)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.foreach(PythonRDD.scala:112)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.to(PythonRDD.scala:112)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.toBuffer(PythonRDD.scala:112)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.toArray(PythonRDD.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:884)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$4.apply(SparkContext.scala:884)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runLocallyWithinThread(DAGScheduler.scala:681)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anon$1.run(DAGScheduler.scala:666)
```

Is spark unable to deal with file larger than my ram? Could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138751/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space/22742982#22742982

Answer (score 5):

Spark can handle some case. But you are using `take` to force Spark to fetch all of the data to an array(in memory). In such case, you should store them to files, like using `saveAsTextFile`.

If you are interested in looking at some of data, you can use `sample` or `takeSample`.

Comment: If I want to use mlib to train all the features samples in the file how can I send all samples to train? Thanks

Comment: Actually, mlib has many algorithms. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: For example, I want to train the data with Logistic Regression. The file has several columns data and each column is a feature. How can I train all the samples in a feature into Logistic Regression?