# OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm facing some problems regarding the memory issue, but I'm unable to solve it. Any help is highly appreciated.
I am new to Spark and pyspark functionalities and trying to read a large JSON file that is around 5GB in size and build the rdd using

```
df = spark.read.json("example.json")
```

Every time I run the above statement, I get the following error :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : Java heap space
```

I need to get the JSON data in form of RDD and then use SQL Spark for manipulating and analysing. But I get error at the first step(reading JSON) itself. 
I am aware that to read such large files necessary changes in the configuration of the Spark Session is required. 
I followed the answers given at [Apache Spark: Job aborted due to stage failure: "TID x failed for unknown reasons"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836401/apache-spark-job-aborted-due-to-stage-failure-tid-x-failed-for-unknown-reason)
and [Spark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138751/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space/22742982#22742982)

I tried to change my SparkSession's configuration but I think I may have misunderstood some of the settings. The following are my spark configuration.

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
.config("spark.memory.fraction", 0.8) \
.config("spark.executor.memory", "14g") \
.config("spark.driver.memory", "12g")\
.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" , "8000") \
.getOrCreate()
```

Is there any mistake in the values that I have set for the different parameters like driver memory and executor memory. Also do I need to a set more config parameters other than this ?

Comment: Are you calling `.collect()` or `.show()` over that DataFrame?

Comment: I want to, once I create the RDD df.

Comment: Try using your json file in hdfs.

Comment: What is the action that you are calling after reading the JSON file? If you aren't, when does the error occur? Is it a normal textfile or compressed? Also, please try without setting `spark.memory.fraction` and [edit] the details in your question. Thanks.

Comment: If you can split the raw JSON file (hopefully it's an array), do so, and place the splits in a folder, and read the folder.

Hopefully you got a tool to split a file that big, I only had to split a 500Mb file, so I used Python.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
df = spark.read.json("example.json").repartition(100)
```

This is due to shuffle data between too small partitions and memory overhead put all the partitions in heap memory.

My suggestion is to reduce the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` value to minimal and try to use re-partition or parallelism to increase partition of your input/intermediate dataframes.

```
spark = SparkSession \
  .builder \
  .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
  .config("spark.memory.fraction", 0.8) \
  .config("spark.executor.memory", "14g") \
  .config("spark.driver.memory", "12g")\
  .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" , "800") \
  .getOrCreate()
```