# Spark groupBy OutOfMemory woes

Tags: apache-spark

I'm doing a simple groupBy on a fairly small dataset (80 files in HDFS, few gigs in total). I'm running Spark on 8 low-memory machines in a yarn cluster, i.e. something along the lines of:

`spark-submit ... --master yarn-client --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 3000m --executor-cores 1`

The dataset consists of strings of length 500-2000.

I'm trying to do a simple `groupByKey` (see below), but it fails with a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` exception

```
val keyvals = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("hdfs://...")
  .map( someobj.produceKeyValTuple )
keyvals.groupByKey().count()
```

I can count the group sizes using `reduceByKey` without problems, ensuring myself the problem isn't caused by a single excessively large group, nor by an excessive amount of groups :

```
keyvals.map(s => (s._1, 1)).reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b).collect().foreach(println)
// produces:
//  (key1,139368)
//  (key2,35335)
//  (key3,392744)
//  ...
//  (key13,197941)
```

I've tried reformatting, reshuffling and increasing the groupBy level of parallelism:

```
keyvals.groupByKey(24).count // fails
keyvals.groupByKey(3000).count // fails
keyvals.coalesce(24, true).groupByKey(24).count // fails
keyvals.coalesce(3000, true).groupByKey(3000).count // fails
keyvals.coalesce(24, false).groupByKey(24).count // fails
keyvals.coalesce(3000, false).groupByKey(3000).count // fails
```

I've tried playing around with `spark.default.parallelism`, and increasing `spark.shuffle.memoryFraction` to `0.8` while lowering `spark.storage.memoryFraction` to `0.1`

The failing stage (count) will fail  on task 2999 of 3000.

I can't seem to find anything that suggests that groupBy shouldn't just spill to disk instead of keeping things in memory, but I just can't get it to work right, even on fairly small datasets. This should obviosuly not be the case, and I must be doing something wrong, but I have no idea where to start debugging this!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22742982/1586965

Comment: Anything in particular? I think I've touched upon most of the points mentioned in that post. Tbh, what I'm really looking for, is an explanation of why groupBy eats up memory, instead of just shuffling to disk.

Comment: Honestly many spark woes can be solved by just upgrading versions, it definitely has its issues but also has a very active community contributing to it

Comment: Same problem on 1.0.0, 1.0.1 and 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Hmm, well if `reduceByKey` works but `groupByKey` doesn't then I find it hard to come to any conclusion other than a large group! 392744 is quite a large number depending on your types.  Have you tried sorting the counts and finding out which is the largest? Are you sure they are all in that order of magnitude??

Comment: Looking closer at the data, there is actually a chance that there's malformed data (very long strings) in certain groups. I'll look further into that. However, I would like to argue that 400,000 keys in a group should be easily handled in Spark - hell, 400,000 3000 character strings should be more than easy enough to handle on a single machine :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Patrick Wendell shed some light on the details of the groupBy operator [on the mailing list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Understanding-RDD-GroupBy-OutOfMemory-Exceptions-td11427.html#a11487). The takeaway message is the following:

> Within a partition things will spill [...] This spilling can only occur *across keys* at the moment. Spilling cannot occur within a key at present. [...] Spilling within one key for GroupBy's is likely to end up in the next release of Spark, Spark 1.2. [...] If the goal is literally to just write out to disk all the values associated with each group, and the values associated with a single group are larger than fit in memory, this cannot be accomplished right now with the groupBy operator.

He further suggests a work-around:

> The best way to work around this depends a bit on what you are trying to do with the data down stream. Typically approaches involve sub-dividing any very large groups, for instance, appending a hashed value in a small range (1-10) to large keys. Then your downstream code has to deal with aggregating partial values for each group. If your goal is just to lay each group out sequentially on disk on one big file, you can call `sortByKey` with a hashed suffix as well. The sort functions are externalized in Spark 1.1 (which is in pre-release).