# Apache Spark fails to process a large Cassandra column family

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to use Apache Spark to process my large (~230k entries) cassandra dataset, but I am constantly running into different kinds of errors. However I can successfully run applications when running on a dataset ~200 entries. I have a spark setup of 3 nodes with 1 master and 2 workers, and the 2 workers also have a cassandra cluster installed with data indexed with a replication factor of 2. My 2 spark workers show 2.4 and 2.8 GB memory on the web interface and I set `spark.executor.memory` to 2409 when running an application, to get a combined memory of 4.7 GB. Here is my WebUI Homepage

[image]

The environment page of one of the tasks

[image: environment]

At this stage, I am simply trying to process data stored in cassandra using spark. Here is the basic code I am using to do this in Java

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true)
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", CASSANDRA_HOST)
        .setJars(jars);

SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(HOST, APP_NAME, conf);
SparkContextJavaFunctions context = javaFunctions(sc);

CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> rdd = context.cassandraTable(CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE, CASSANDRA_COLUMN_FAMILY);

System.out.println(rdd.count());
```

For a successful run, on a small dataset (200 entries), the events interface looks something like this

[image]

But when I run the same thing on a large dataset (i.e. I change only the `CASSANDRA_COLUMN_FAMILY`), the job never terminates inside the terminal, the log looks like this

[image]

and after ~2 minutes, the stderr for the executors looks like this

[image]

and after ~7 minutes, I get

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

in my terminal, and I have to manually kill the `SparkSubmit` process. However, the large dataset was indexed from a binary file that occupied only 22 MB, and doing `nodetool status`, I can see that only ~115 MB data is stored in both of my cassandra nodes. I have also tried to use Spark SQL on my dataset, but have got similar results with that too. Where am I going wrong with my setup, and what should I do to successfully process my dataset, for both a Transformation-Action program and a program that uses Spark SQL.

I have already tried the following methods

- Using `-Xms1G -Xmx1G` to increase memory, but the program fails with an exception saying that I should instead set `spark.executor.memory`, which I have.
- Using `spark.cassandra.input.split.size`, which fails saying it isn't a valid option, and a similar option is `spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb`, which I set to 1, with no effect.

**EDIT**

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22742982/3673043) answer, I have also tried the following methods:

- set `spark.storage.memoryFraction` to 0
- not set `spark.storage.memoryFraction` to zero and use `persist` with `MEMORY_ONLY`, `MEMORY_ONLY_SER`, `MEMORY_AND_DISK` and `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`.

Versions:

- Spark: 1.4.0
- Cassandra: 2.1.6
- spark-cassandra-connector: 1.4.0-M1

Comment: Try increasing the driver memory . The default is 512MB for driver

Comment: I have tried to set different values for `spark.driver.memory`, based on my `free -m` output, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is a issue in the latest spark-cassandra-connector. The parameter `spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb` is supposed to have a default value of 64 MB which is being interpreted as 64 bytes in the code. This causes too many partitions to be created, which can't be scheduled by spark. Try setting the conf value to

```
spark.cassandra.input.split.size_in_mb=67108864
```

Comment: Indeed, there seems to be a bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. For now, it works for an input of 230782 records, with  a standard program taking ~5 minutes with 3 partitions, while an equivalent spark SQL program made 7 partitions and finished in under 8 seconds ! Cheers !

Comment: This is really pathetic. I wasted my 2 days figuring out the problem and here it goes. I was suffering from the same problem. Thanks