# How to know deploy mode of PySpark application?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, pyspark

I am trying to fix an issue with running out of memory, and I want to know whether I need to change these settings in the default configurations file (`spark-defaults.conf`) in the spark home folder.  Or, if I can set them in the code.

I saw this question [PySpark: java.lang.OutofMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336915/pyspark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space) and it says that it depends on if I'm running in `client` mode.  I'm running spark on a cluster and monitoring it using standalone.

But, how do I figure out if I'm running spark in `client` mode?

Comment: By default, spark would run in the `client` mode. In case you want to change this, you can set the variable `--deploy-mode` to `cluster`. Since the default is `client` mode, unless you have made any changes, I suppose you would be running in the client mode itself.

Comment: That is useful information about the difference between the two modes, but that doesn't help me know if spark is running in cluster mode or client mode.  I am working on a production environment, and I run pyspark in an IPython notebook.  I have ssh access to the namenode, and I know where spark home is, but beyond that I don't know where to get the information about whether spark is running in `client` or `cluster` mode.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

If you are running an interactive shell, e.g. `pyspark` (CLI or via an IPython notebook), by default you are running in `client` mode. You can easily verify that you **cannot** run `pyspark` or any other interactive shell in `cluster` mode:

```
$ pyspark --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster
Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar 22 2016, 01:42:54)
[GCC Intel(R) C++ gcc 4.8 mode] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Error: Cluster deploy mode is not applicable to Spark shells.

$ spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster
Error: Cluster deploy mode is not applicable to Spark shells.
```

Examining the contents of the `bin/pyspark` file may be instructive, too - here is the final line (which is the actual executable):

```
$ pwd
/home/ctsats/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6
$ cat bin/pyspark
[...]
exec "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-submit pyspark-shell-main --name "PySparkShell" "$@"
```

i.e. `pyspark` is actually a script run by `spark-submit` and given the name `PySparkShell`, by which you can find it in the Spark History Server UI; and since it is run like that, it goes by whatever arguments (or defaults) are included with its `spark-submit` command.

Comment: OP asked about how to know the deploy mode of a *running* spark (application).

Comment: And you consider this reason for downvoting? At the end, my answer does address the question, which is how to *know*... Question is also clearly about the pyspark API, not Scala - nevertheless, I upvoted your answer because I learned something (and this is my main criterion for upvoting...).

Comment: Thanks @desertnaut. I appreciate the upvoting. My downvoting was to mark your answer as slightly offbase -- you didn't really answer the question (I may've not either but left the OP with a home work :))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would argue though that "slightly offbase" answers do not deserve downvotings...

Answer (score 9):

Since `sc.deployMode` is not available in PySpark, you could check out `spark.submit.deployMode` configuration property.

```
>>> sc.getConf().get("spark.submit.deployMode")
'client'
```

### This is not available in PySpark

Use `sc.deployMode`

```
scala> sc.deployMode
res0: String = client

scala> sc.version
res1: String = 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: For me, `sc.getConf().get("spark.submit.deployMode")` worked - notice the extra paranthesis after `getConf` because it is a function. I am on pyspark==3.2.1

Comment: Correct. For PySpark users, the round brackets are a must (unlike Scala).

Answer (score 1):

As of Spark 2+ the below works.

```
for item in spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll():print(item)

(u'spark.submit.deployMode', u'client') # will be one of the items in the list.
```