# Can I run a pyspark jupyter notebook in cluster deploy mode?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

**Context:**
The cluster configuration is as follows:

- Everything is running withing docker files.
- node1: spark master
- node2: jupyter hub (where I run my notebooks as well)
- node3-7: spark worker nodes
- I can telnet and ping from my worker nodes to node2 and vice versa using the default ports for spark

**Problem:**
I'm trying to create a spark session in pyspark jupyter notebook which runs in cluster deploy mode. I'm trying to get the driver to run on a node that isn't the node where the jupyter notebook is run from. Right now I can run jobs on the cluster but only with the driver running on node2.

After a lot of digging I found this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38457052/7860754) which claims that if you run an interactive shell with spark you can only do so in local deploy mode (where the driver is located on the machine you are working on). That post goes on to say that something like jupyter hub as result also won't work in cluster deploy mode but I am unable to find any documentation that can confirm this. Can someone confirm if jupyter hub can run in cluster mode at all?

My attempt at running the spark session in cluster deployed mode:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
.enableHiveSupport()\
.config("spark.local.ip",<node 3 ip>)\
.config("spark.driver.host",<node 3 ip>)\
.config('spark.submit.deployMode','cluster')\
.getOrCreate()
```

**Error:**

```
/usr/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    167                     for key, value in self._options.items():
    168                         sparkConf.set(key, value)
--> 169                     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    170                     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
    171                     for key, value in self._options.items():

/usr/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    308         with SparkContext._lock:
    309             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 310                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    311             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    312 

/usr/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    113         """
    114         self._callsite = first_spark_call() or CallSite(None, None, None)
--> 115         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

/usr/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    257         with SparkContext._lock:
    258             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 259                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    260                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    261 

/usr/spark/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf)
     93                 callback_socket.close()
     94         if gateway_port is None:
---> 95             raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before     sending the driver its port number")
     96 
     97         # In Windows, ensure the Java child processes do not linger after Python has exited.

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You cannot use cluster mode with PySpark at all](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit):

> Currently, standalone mode does not support cluster mode for Python applications.

and even if you could [cluster mode is not applicable in interactive environment](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6c18d8d8079ac4d2d6dc7539601ab83fc5b51760/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit.scala#L292-L295):

```scala
case (_, CLUSTER) if isShell(args.primaryResource) =>
  error("Cluster deploy mode is not applicable to Spark shells.")
case (_, CLUSTER) if isSqlShell(args.mainClass) =>
  error("Cluster deploy mode is not applicable to Spark SQL shell.")
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this is true for standalone mode (like in the original question). If you're using other cluster manager (such as Yarn), you can submit jobs in cluster mode with PySpark.

Comment: Topic question was regarding cluster deployment. Statement "You cannot use cluster mode with PySpark at all" is not correct - we do use pyspark with `yarn-cluster` mode all the time in production. Error @J Schmidt pointed at is not related to pyspark running in standalone mode.. actually his example shows `.config('spark.submit.deployMode','cluster')` which is not a standalone mode. Thanks.

Comment: Think this is outdated now!

Answer (score 4):

1. One "supported" way to indirectly use **yarn-cluster** mode in `Jupyter` 
   is through 
   [Apache Livy](https://livy.apache.org/)

[image: Apache Livy architecture]

Basically, `Livy` is a REST API service for `Spark` cluster.

`Jupyter` has a extension "[spark-magic](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic)" that allows to integrate `Livy` with `Jupyter`

[image: spark magic architecture]

An example of `Jupyter` with `Spark-magic` bound (driver runs in the yarn cluster and not locally in this case, as mentioned above):

[image: sparkmagic example]

2. Another way to use `YARN-cluster` mode in Jupyter is to use `Jupyter Enterprise Gateway` https://jupyter-enterprise-gateway.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kernel-yarn-cluster-mode.html#configuring-kernels-for-yarn-cluster-mode
3. There are also commercial options that normally use one of the methods I listed above. Some of our users for example are on IBM DSX (aka IBM Watson Studio Local) use `Apache Livy` - option number one above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in PySpark, but did you try to change the kernel.json file of pyspark jupyter kernel ?

Maybe you can add the option deploy mode cluster in it

```
"env": {
  "SPARK_HOME": "/your_dir/spark",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/your_dir/spark/python:/your_dir/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/your_dir/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master local[*] pyspark-shell"
 }
```

And you change this line :

```
"PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master local[*] pyspark-shell"
```

with your cluster master ip and **--deploy-mode cluster**

Not sure that will change anything, but maybe that works, and I would love to know too !

Good luck

EDIT : I found this maybe that can help yuo even though it's from 2015

[link jupyter pyspark cluster](https://arnesund.com/2015/09/21/spark-cluster-on-openstack-with-multi-user-jupyter-notebook/)