# Apply function per group in pyspark -pandas_udf (No module named pyarrow)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I am trying to apply a function to each group of a dataset in pyspark. The first error I was getting was

> ```
> Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o62.__getnewargs__. Trace:
> py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
> ```

To solve the above, I removed the spark function (I had `spark.range()`). Now the error is solved but I now get the following:

> ```
> File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 276, in load_stream
>     import pyarrow as pa
> ImportError: No module named pyarrow
> ```

But when I try it on its own it works, ie.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pyarrow.Table
a: int64
__index_level_0__: int64
metadata
--------
{'pandas': '{"pandas_version": "0.23.0", "index_columns": ["__index_level_0__"], "columns": [{"metadata": null, "field_name": "a", "name": "a", "numpy_type": "int64", "pandas_type": "int64"}, {"metadata": null, "field_name": "__index_level_0__", "name": null, "numpy_type": "int64", "pandas_type": "int64"}], "column_indexes": [{"metadata": null, "field_name": null, "name": null, "numpy_type": "object", "pandas_type": "bytes"}]}'}
```

**EXAMPLE THAT FAILS** - Taken from [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd

cols = ['id', 'val']
vals = [('A', 5), ('A', 3), ('A', 7), ('B', 12), ('B', 15), ('C', 3)]
d1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vals, cols)

>>> @F.pandas_udf(d1.schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
... def subtract_mean(pdf):
...     return pdf.assign(v=pdf.v - pdf.v.mean())
...
>>> try1 = d1.groupby('id').apply(subtract_mean)
>>> try1.show()
```

If I try to convert to pandas dataframe, it does not work because It does not have the `schema` attribute.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pyarrow` has to be present on the path on each worker node.

- If you run this code on as single node, make sure that `PYSPARK_PYTHON` (and optionally its `PYTHONPATH`) are the same as the interpreter you use to test `pyarrow` code.
- If you use cluster, make sure that `pyarrow` is installed on each node, additionally to points made above.

Moreover make sure that installed `pyarrow` version is greater or equal than minimum supported ([0.8 today](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2cb976355c615eee4ebd0a86f3911fa9284fccf6/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py#L139)) - although this should cause different exception.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I m on a cluster so this could be it. I just talked with the dev that installed spark et al, and he wasn't sure. I will leave this question open until I test it tomorrow. If that was it I will accept your answer.

Comment: I am getting the same error from pyspark interactive shell. However [pyspark always runs in client mode] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38384224/how-to-know-deploy-mode-of-pyspark-application) then why do we need to pyarrow is installed on each node?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer :

One issue can be *user delegation*: *ie*

- python module installed with `userx`
- spark-submit launched by `userx`
- but `spark` is the technical user executing logic on the workers.
  (behind the scenes, without you noticing).

It might be that `spark`is not seeing the module.

**To fix that :**
`su` as `spark`, and install the missing module via `pip`install
(on all workers)

That fixed it for me.

Edit :
depending on your settings `pyspark` shell might still be able to see your module though.