# Is there a spark-defaults.conf when installed with pip install pyspark

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, config, heap-memory

I installed `pyspark` with `pip`.
I code in `jupyter` notebooks. Everything works fine but not I got a `java` heap space error when exporting a large `.csv` file.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336915/pyspark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space) someone suggested editing the `spark-defaults.config`. Also in the spark documentation, it says

> "Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the
>   SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has
>   already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the
>   --driver-memory command line option or in your default properties file."

But I'm afraid there is no such file when installing `pyspark` with `pip`.
I'm I right? How do I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I also have this problem for PySpark in Conda..

Answer (score 8):

I recently ran into this as well. If you look at the Spark UI under the `Classpath Entries`, the first path is probably the configuration directory, something like `/.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/conf/`. When I looked for that directory, it didn't exist; presumably it's not part of the `pip` installation. However, you can easily create it and add your own configuration files. For example,

```sh
mkdir /.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/conf
vi /.../lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

Comment: works flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

The `spark-defaults.conf` file should be located in:

```
$SPARK_HOME/conf
```

If no file is present, create one (a template should be available in the same directory).

**How to find the default configuration folder**

Check contents of the folder in Python:

```
import glob, os
glob.glob(os.path.join(os.environ["SPARK_HOME"], "conf", "spark*"))
# ['/usr/local/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/conf/spark-env.sh.template',
#  '/usr/local/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/conf/spark-defaults.conf.template']
```

**When no `spark-defaults.conf` file is available, built-in values are used**

To my surprise, no `spark-defaults.conf` but just a template file was present!

Still I could look at Spark properties, either in the “Environment” tab of the Web UI `http://<driver>:4040` or using `getConf().getAll()` on the Spark context:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("myApp") \
        .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
# [('spark.driver.port', '55128'),
#  ('spark.app.name', 'myApp'),
#  ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
#  ('spark.sql.warehouse.dir', 'file:/path/spark-warehouse'),
#  ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
#  ('spark.master', 'local[*]'),
#  ('spark.submit.pyFiles', ''),
#  ('spark.app.startTime', '1645484409629'),
#  ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
#  ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
#  ('spark.app.id', 'local-1645484410352'),
#  ('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true'),
#  ('spark.driver.host', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')]
```

Note that not all properties are listed but:

> *only values explicitly specified through spark-defaults.conf, SparkConf, or the command line. For all other configuration properties, you can assume the default value is used.*

For instance, consider the default parallelism is in my case:

```
spark._sc.defaultParallelism
8
```

This is the default for local mode, namely the number of cores on the local machine--see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html. In my case 8=2x4cores because of hyper-threading.

If passed the property `spark.default.parallelism` when launching the app

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Set parallelism") \
        .config("spark.default.parallelism", 4) \
        .getOrCreate()
```

then the property is shown in the Web UI and in the list

```
spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
```

**Precedence of configuration settings**

Spark will consider given properties in this order (`spark-defaults.conf` comes last):

1. `SparkConf`
2. flags passed to `spark-submit`
3. `spark-defaults.conf`

From https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties:

> *Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file. A few configuration keys have been renamed since earlier versions of Spark; in such cases, the older key names are still accepted, but take lower precedence than any instance of the newer key.*

**Note**
Some pyspark Jupyter kernels contain flags for `spark-submit` in the environment variable `$PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`, so one might want to check that too.

Related question: [Where to modify spark-defaults.conf if I installed pyspark via pip install pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253784/where-to-modify-spark-defaults-conf-if-i-installed-pyspark-via-pip-install-pyspa/)

Answer (score 0):

The `spark-defaults.config` file is needed when we have to change any of the default configs for spark.

As @niuer suggested, it should be present in the `$SPARK_HOME/conf/` directory. But that might not be the case with you. By default, a template config file will be present there. You can just add a new `spark-defaults.conf` file in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/`.

Answer (score -1):

Check your `spark` path. There are configuration files under: 
`$SPARK_HOME/conf/`, e.g. 
`spark-defaults.conf`.