# Where to modify spark-defaults.conf if I installed pyspark via pip install pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I installed pyspark 3.2.0 via `pip install pyspark`. I have installed pyspark in a conda environment named pyspark. I cannot find `spark-defaults.conf`. I am searching for it in `~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark` since that is my understanding of what SPARK_HOME should be.

1. Where can I find spark-defaults.conf? I want to modify it
2. Am I right in setting SPARK_HOME to the installation location of pyspark `~/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2`. The `SPARK_HOME` environment variables are configured correctly.

`1`. In the pip installation environment, the `$SPARK_HOME/conf` directory needs to be created manually, then copy the configuration file template to this directory and modify each configuration file.