# where do I create a spark configuration file and set.driver.memory to 2gb?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark and relatively new to Linux in general. I am running Spark on local Ubuntu in client mode. I have RAM of 16 GB. I installed apache spark following this [link.](https://kontext.tech/article/445/install-hadoop-330-on-windows-10-using-wsl) And I am able to run and process large volume of data. The challenge is exporting the resulting data frames in csv. With even 100k rows of data I am getting all sorts of memory issues. On contrast I was able to process partitioned python files of totaling several millions of rows.

Based on lots of googling, I believe the problem lies with my spark.driver.memory. I need to change this but since I am running on client mode I should change it in some configuration file. How can I locate if I have an existing Spark configuration file or how do I create a new one and set spark.driver.memory to 2GB.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default value for all sessions in

```
$SPARK_HOME/spark-defaults.conf
```

If you do not find `spark-defaults.conf` you should have a file `spark-defaults.conf.template`, just `cp spark-defaults.conf.template spark-defaults.conf` and edit it uncommenting the line:

```
# spark.driver.memory              5g
```

Alternatively, you can set the value just for the current session using `.config` in the session builder:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
       .master("local[*]") \
       .appName("myApp") \
       .config("spark.driver.memory", "5g") \
       .getOrCreate()
```

(perhaps you might also want to increase `spark.executor.memory`)

See also [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71214326/2314737) to a similar question.

Comment: I could not find any value in $SPARK_HOME for ex:-  (py_env) user@laptop:~$ echo "$SPARK_HOME" returns nothing.  Q1) Can I export a path to $SPARK_HOME?

Comment: Q2) Does it need to be a specific path?  Q3) I could not find spark-defaults.conf.template or spark-defaults.conf anywhere in machine. Can I download sample spark-defaults.conf.template from web?

Comment: (py_env) user@laptop:~$ find -name spark

./anaconda3/envs/py_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/pandas/spark

./anaconda3/pkgs/pyspark-3.2.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0/site-packages/pyspark/pandas/spark

Comment: try a global search `find / -name "spark-defaults*" 2>/dev/null`  (it might take long)

Comment: :( ran the above command; It ran for a while and then returns nothing.

Comment: How are you running Spark jobs? In a spark-shell? In Python with `import pyspark`? Please provide a [mcve] (as much as possible)

Comment: I installed pyspark using anaconda and not downloading directly from apache site. I just removed pyspark packages from anaconda and installed from apache site. I hope I can figure the rest out as all the suggestions are based with assumption that pyspark is installed by downloading it from apache site.