# Out of memory error when converting pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, java, pandas, pyspark, out-of-memory

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of 180M rows and 4 columns (all integers). I saved it as a pickle file and the file is 5.8GB. I'm trying to convert the pandas dataframe to pyspark dataframe using `spark_X = spark.createDataFrame(X)`, but keep getting a "out of memory" error.

The error snippet is

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.readRDDFromFile. : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I have over 200GB of memory and I don't think a lack of physical memory is the issue. I read that there are multiple memory limitations, e.g. driver memory - could this be the cause?

How can I resolve or workaround this?

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336915/pyspark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Comment: Thanks, I'll give them a try.

Comment: @Rayne When you say you have 200GB memory, is it the total resource in your cluster? Also, which mode and what config are you using?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, this is the physical memory I have. Anyway, I have not encountered this problem after changing the `spark.driver.memory` setting to `32g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @bzu, the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336915/pyspark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space) solved my problem.

I did have to manually create the `$SPARK_HOME/conf` folder and `spark-defaults.conf` file, though, as they did not exist. Also, I changed the setting to

```
spark.driver.memory 32g
```