# Spark Out O fMemory Error

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory

I run a scrip on spark/scala to collect a calculated results. The result data set is not too large however when I run the following:

```
Result.collect()
```

I get the following error:

```
#java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 10466"...
/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-shell: line 41: 10466 Killed                         " $FWDIR"/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main --name "Spark shell" "$@"
```

I am not sure why I got this error for running scala I used the following command to increase my memory:

```
spark-shell driver-memory 8G --executor-memory 8G --executor-cores 4 --num-executors 5
```

Could you please help on this?

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: This is great group of answers if you haven't checked it out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138751/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space.

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful.Actually increasing the partition size resoled the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a collect, you should look into
 `spark.driver.maxResultSize`
also in your spark-shell you missed the -- while specifying the driver-memory.