# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Hy,

I have a dataframe in a sparkcontext with 400k rows and 3 columns.
Driver has 143.5 of Storage Memory

```
16/03/21 19:52:35 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:55613 with 143.5 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 55613)
16/03/21 19:52:35 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
```

I want returns the contents of this DataFrame as Pandas

I did

```
df_users =  UserDistinct.toPandas()
```

but I have this error

```
16/03/21 20:01:08 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 7.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 439)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16/03/21 20:01:08 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-0,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How is this possible if I have 143.5 GB RAM?
What can I do?

**EDIT**

My spark-defaults

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

# Default system properties included when running spark-submit.
# This is useful for setting default environmental settings.

# Example:
# spark.master                     spark://master:7077
#spark.eventLog.enabled           true
# spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://namenode:8021/directory
# spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory              200g
# spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
```

my spark context

```
conf = SparkConf()

conf.set("spark.app.name","teste")
conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize","0")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

[image]

EDIT

All steps

```
#import data for a pandas dataframe

df_ora = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)

#change for Spark dataframe and some transformation

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df_oraAS = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df_ora)
df_oraAS.registerTempTable("df_oraAS")

#new column
df_with_C = df_oraAS.withColumn("BUY", lit(1))

indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="ENT_EMAIL", outputCol="user")

#index because I want use recommendation system
user_PK = indexer.fit(df_with_C).transform(df_with_C)

#distinct
UserDistinct = user_PK.dropDuplicates(['ENT_EMAIL' ,'user'])

#data in Pandas dataframe
df_users =  UserDistinct.toPandas()
```

New Edit

change for Driver 60g and Executor 60g

Error:

```
16/03/22 09:53:40 INFO MemoryStore: Block taskresult_446 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1978.5 MB, free 22.5 GB)
16/03/22 09:53:40 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added taskresult_446 in memory on localhost:56281 (size: 1978.5 MB, free: 20.4 GB)
16/03/22 09:53:40 INFO Executor: Finished task 14.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 446). 2074557399 bytes result sent via BlockManager)
16/03/22 09:53:40 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 25.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 457, localhost, partition 25,NODE_LOCAL, 1999 bytes)
16/03/22 09:53:40 INFO Executor: Running task 25.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 457)
16/03/22 09:53:40 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 8 non-empty blocks out of 8 blocks
16/03/22 09:53:40 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/03/22 09:53:40 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 8 non-empty blocks out of 8 blocks
16/03/22 09:53:40 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/03/22 09:54:04 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 18.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 450)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16/03/22 09:54:04 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 26.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 458, localhost, partition 26,NODE_LOCAL, 1999 bytes)
16/03/22 09:54:04 INFO Executor: Running task 26.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 458)
16/03/22 09:54:04 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-5,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
16/03/22 09:54:05 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 8 non-empty blocks out of 8 blocks
16/03/22 09:54:05 INFO ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
16/03/22 09:54:05 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/03/22 09:54:06 WARN QueuedThreadPool: 6 threads could not be stopped
16/03/22 09:54:06 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.10.5.105:4040
16/03/22 09:54:08 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 6 (toPandas at <stdin>:1) failed in 385.120 s
16/03/22 09:54:08 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 3 failed: toPandas at <stdin>:1, took 398.921433 s
16/03/22 09:54:09 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread task-result-getter-1
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:585)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetRemote(BlockManager.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1741)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "task-result-getter-1" java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:585)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetRemote(BlockManager.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1741)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:50)
    ... 3 more
16/03/22 09:54:09 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread task-result-getter-2
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doGetRemote$2.apply(BlockManager.scala:585)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetRemote(BlockManager.scala:585)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1741)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Apache/spark-1.6.0/python/pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 1378, in toPandas
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)
  File "C:/Apache/spark-1.6.0/python/pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 280, in collect
    port = self._jdf.collectToPython()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "C:/Apache/spark-1.6.0/python/pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
```

Comment: Do you mean the machine running the driver has 143.5GB RAM? What about your settings, what do you have in `spark-defaults.conf`, and `spark-env.sh`? Are you passing any options when launching `pyspark`?

Comment: @mattinbits, I edit my question with spark defaults and spark context.

Comment: You could try to cache table before feeding it to indexer if it fits into the memory. This will speed up everything and avoid recreating a lot of small objects.

Answer (score 12):

For some reason Spark wants to serialize some data. Apparently it does so by writing to a [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). From the docs:

> This class implements an output stream in which the data is written
>   into a byte array. The buffer automatically grows as data is written
>   to it. The data can be retrieved using toByteArray() and toString().

The key word here is **a** (one!) byte array. Java byte arrays have a maximum length of `2^31-1=2147483647` bytes = 2GB. So as soon as Spark attempts to serialize anything that's greater than 2GB, you'll get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

And that's exactly what happened here.

To solve this issue, file a bug report with Spark. The culprit is `org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize()`, which assumes that nothing you ever want to serialize can be larger than 2GB in its serialized form.

Comment: I using pyspark and load data using `binaryfiles('*.tar')` and then `flatmap(process)`. I did observe this error occur when dealing with tar files >3GB but totally fine with files lower than 2GB. I am assuming my `process` function return a giant list that probably exceed the 2GB limit Hendrik mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the storage you are referring to is disk space.

What is happening is that your application is running out of RAM; not disk space.

`OutOfMemoryError` is covered extensively in this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138751/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

By default, only so much memory is allocated to your driver in executor. Usually around 500MB - 5GB. If you are running spark locally, you will need to adjust the driver memory.

The [Spark Documentation - Memory Management](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management) details all of the parameters/options you can configure. These can be found in:

```
$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

Try adjusting your `driver-memory` in that file.

However, if you are running your application using `spark-submit`, you can pass the driver-memory as an option like so:

```
spark-1.6.1/bin/spark-submit
  --class "MyClass"
  --driver-memory 12g
  --master local[*] 
  target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar
```

Comment: Brian Vanover, it's is RAM... I edit my question with spark context and a picture with executor. Thks for your help

Comment: @Kardu How are you submitting your application? Try using `spark-submit` like my example above, but instead of jar, submit your `.py` file. This link contains a python example: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: I tried Brian...In my spark-defaults.conf I try 20, 100, 150g. Many combination between drived and executor error and.... Same error... I try to make UserDistinct.collect() and I have the same error too..  I don't understand why I need so many RAM in so smaller dataset...

Comment: `collect` is a risky function to call, because it essentially brings your entire dataset into memory. I had the same problem as you before, and I fixed it by modifying my options when executing `spark-submit`

Comment: When I call .toPandas() is the same idea? I call all dataset to my drive memory right? I really don't understand why need so many memory for a dataframe with 400 rows and 3 column but ok... Thanks for your help @Brian Vanover

Answer (score -2):

I have the similar situation. The best solution I came up with is to save spark dataframe to parquet file and then read this file using `fastparquet`

Also a good idea would be to switch from pandas dataframes to [dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) dataframes because it can keep data not just in memory like pandas but can keep on disk.