# Converting PySpark DataFrame to Pandas using Apache Arrow

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-arrow

I'd like to convert a `PySpark` DataFrame (`pyspark.sql.DataFrame`) to `Pandas` dataframe. There is a builtin method `toPandas()` which is very inefficient (Please read Wes McKinney'd article about this issue back in Fenruary 2017 [here](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/pandas-and-apache-arrow/) and his calculation in [this jupyter notebook](https://gist.github.com/wesm/0cb5531b1c2e346a0007)).

In the meantime, some efforts have been done to make such a conversion faster. An example, would be Josh's function [here](https://gist.github.com/joshlk/871d58e01417478176e7). However, that did not help me since I am looking to transfer +1M rows from `pysaprk.DataFrame` to `Pandas`, this solution did not work for me.

Luckily, as shown in [this post](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/07/26/spark-arrow/) in July 26th 2017, thanks to authors [Wes](https://github.com/wesm), [Li](https://github.com/icexelloss) and [Holden](https://github.com/holdenk), the functionality of `toPandas()` has been significantly improved thanks to implementation of `Apache Arrow` in `Spark 2.3`. That being said, I don't have access to Spark 2.3 (I am using Spark 2.1).

So, my question is how I can use `Apache Arrow` functionalities to convert `pyspark` dataframe to `Pandas` fast for `Spark` older than 2.1. I think a lot of people are stuck with older versions of `Spark` and can benefit from this.

**Update 1**: I have been suggested to print `pyspark` to `CSV` files first and then read `CSV` files from `Pandas` powerful `read_csv` method. I am really hopeful that I will find a way to avoid doing that!

**Update 2:** The reasoning behind slowness of `toPandas()` method and possible `out of memory` issues are discussed in details in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36140493/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-in-pyspark)

```python
dfSpark = spark.sql(sqlQuery)
df = dfSpark.toPandas() # Very slow / out of memory error
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an intermediate file?

You can save the file to parquet from spark, then read it in pandas.

```
#spark dataframe 
df.write.parquet("path/file.parquet")
```

see more : 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files

check out pyarrow read parquet files:

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
table = pq.read_table('example.parquet') 

#or if you want to only read some of the colums 
table = pq.read_table('example.parquet', columns=['one', 'three'])

df = table.to_pandas()  #pandas df
```

Also, if you are running out of memory, sample the df, or filter it before writing it.