# apache spark "Py4JError: Answer from Java side is empty"

Tags: apache-spark

I get this error every time...
I use sparkling water... 
My conf-file:

```
***"spark.driver.memory 65g
spark.python.worker.memory 65g
spark.master local[*]"***
```

The amount of data is about 5 Gb.
There is no another information about this error...
Does anybody know why it happens? Thank you!

```
***"ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:Error while sending or receiving.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/analytics/Spark1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 746, in send_command
    raise Py4JError("Answer from Java side is empty")
Py4JError: Answer from Java side is empty
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/analytics/Spark1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 690, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/analytics/Spark1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 690, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/analytics/Spark1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 690, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused"***
```

Comment: In my case for this generic exception it helped: not to install spark after installing of databrics-connect tool since last one brings it own spark as well, based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57151822/2957102

Answer (score 9):

Usually, you'll see this error when the Java process get silently killed by the OOM Killer.

The OOM Killer (Out of Memory Killer) is a Linux process that kicks in when the system becomes critically low on memory. It selects a process based on its "badness" score and kills it to reclaim memory.
Read more on OOM Killer [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html).

Increasing `spark.executor.memory` and/or `spark.driver.memory` values will only make things worse in this case, i.e. you may want to do the opposite!

Other options would be to:

- increase the number of partitions if you're working with very big data sources;
- increase the number of worker nodes;
- add more physical memory to worker/driver nodes;

Or, if you're running your driver/workers using docker:

- increase docker memory limit;
- set `--oom-kill-disable` on your containers, but make sure you understand possible consequences!

Read more on `--oom-kill-disable` and other docker memory settings [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#memory).

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried setting `spark.executor.memory` and `spark.driver.memory` in your Spark configuration file?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22742982/5453184 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Another point to note if you are on `wsl2` using pyspark. Ensure that your `wsl2` config file has an increased memory.

```
# Settings apply across all Linux distros running on WSL 2
[wsl2]

# Limits VM memory to use no more than 4 GB, this can be set as whole numbers using GB or MB
memory=12GB  # This was originally set to 3gb which caused me to fail since spark.executor.memory and spark.driver.memory was only able to MAX of 3gb regardless of how high i set it. 

# Sets the VM to use eight virtual processors
processors=8
```

for reference. your `.wslconfig` config file should be located in `C:\Users\USERNAME`