# How to write Huge Data ( almost 800 GB) as a hive orc table in HDFS using SPARK?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working in `Spark Project` since last 3-4 months and recently.

I am doing some calculation with a huge history file (800 GB) and a small incremental file (3 GB).

The calculation is happening very fast in spark using `hqlContext` & `dataframe`, but when I am trying to write the calculated result as a `hive table` with `orc` format which will contain almost 20 billion of records with a data size of almost 800 GB is taking too much time (more than 2 hours and finally getting failed).

My cluster details are: 19 nodes , 1.41 TB of Total Memory, Total VCores are 361.

For tuneup I am using

```
--num-executors 67
--executor-cores 6
--executor-memory 60g
--driver-memory 50g
--driver-cores 6
--master yarn-cluster
--total-executor-cores 100
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC"
```

at run time.

If I take a count of result, then it is completing within 15 minutes, but if I want to write that result in HDFS as hive table.

```
[ UPDATED_RECORDS.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("HIST_ORC_TARGET") ]
```

then I am facing the above issue.

Please provide me with a suggestion or anything regarding this as I am stuck in this case since last couple of days.

Code format:

```
val BASE_RDD_HIST = hqlContext.sql("select * from hist_orc")
val BASE_RDD_INCR = hqlContext.sql("select * from incr_orc")
```

some spark calculation using dataframe, hive query & udf.....

Finally:

```
result.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("HIST_ORC_TARGET_TABLE")
```

Comment: When your project fails, what's the error message? Is it Out of Memory? If so, these tuning tips may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138751/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Comment: 16/06/30 13:58:19 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: Asked to send map output locations for shuffle 0 to g4t7550.houston.hpecorp.net:53074
16/06/30 13:58:41 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 22.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 918, g4t7567.houston.hpecorp.net): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.spark.unsafe.memory.HeapMemoryAllocator.allocate(HeapMemoryAllocator.java:66)
        at org.apache.spark.memory.TaskMemoryManager.allocatePage(TaskMemoryManager.java:259)
        at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocatePage(MemoryConsumer.java:112)
        at

Answer (score 2):

Hello friends I have found the answer of my own question few days back so here
I am writing that.

Whenever we execute any spark program we do not specify the `queue` parameter and some time the default queue has some limitations which does not allow you to execute as many executors or tasks that you want so it might cause a slow processing and later on a cause of job failure for memory issue as you are running less executors/tasks. So don't forget to mention a queue name at in your execution command:

```
spark-submit --class com.xx.yy.FactTable_Merging.ScalaHiveHql
    --num-executors 25
    --executor-cores 5
    --executor-memory 20g
    --driver-memory 10g
    --driver-cores 5
    --master yarn-cluster
    --name "FactTable HIST & INCR Re Write After Null Merging Seperately"
    --queue "your_queue_name"
    /tmp/ScalaHiveProgram.jar
    /user/poc_user/FactTable_INCR_MERGED_10_PARTITION
    /user/poc_user/FactTable_HIST_MERGED_50_PARTITION
```