# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I tried to do an algorithm(Fast Fourier Transform, FFT) in Spark.

When data is over 64m(Though it is really small.), The console shows the message:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java heap space.
```

I use 32-bit Ubuntu system and Spark-1.6.0. And I use the Scala IDE, eclipse.

I use local mode and standalone mode. When the data is smaller than 32m, it works well, but when the data is larger than 64m, It cannot work.

I have tried to set the JVM settings to `-Xms1000m` and `-Xmx4000m`. I also tried to add  `.set("spark.exetutor.memory", "8g")` when creating the `SparkConf` in the code. But both of them do not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138751/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Comment: The problem is solved. I used a 32-bit ubuntu... Change it to a 64-bit system, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

if you work with `spark.master = local`, then the relevant value to adjust is `spark.driver.memory`. Note that this option needs to be set before the JVM (i.e. the driver) is launched in local mode, so modifiyng the existing `SparkContext` won't help, because the JVM is already launched.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I find my problem is that the system is 32-bit. I reinstalled a 64-bit system and the problem is solved.