# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error whithin a task in Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, heap-memory

I am receiving `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error inside a function (run as a task in Spark) when trying to build a large String. My question, is which Spark parameter should I tune to avoid this error. I can increase the executors' memory of course. But what is the most memory efficient way of optimizing this. I am using Yarn, so would it be better to just increase `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` to an amount big enough to avoid this error? Note that my strings are that big either. Maybe 1 or 2 GBs only while I give 6 GB for executors.

Comment: check if this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/22742982/2299040

Comment: But how many of those strings are there ? Or some other values which exist in the same scope.

Comment: Also... there is one very important thing that you need to know... Strings are immutable in Java. So of your do something like `String s =  "a"; s = s + "b"; s = s + "c"`. Every concatenation create a new string while the old one is left of to be garbage collected later. And hence if you create a large String using concatenation then you will actually have many strings. Use `StringBuilder` to avoid those multiple copies.

Comment: I know. Of course I am not making strings like that.