# Slave lost error in pyspark

Tags: memory, pyspark, out

[image: picture from spark UI]

I'm using Spark1.6
I'm running a simple df.show(2) method and got errors like

```
    An error occurred while calling o143.showString.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage      
    failure: Task 6 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure:
     Lost task 6.3 in stage 6.0 
     ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the 
     running tasks) Reason: Slave lost
```

When I did persist, through spark UI I saw the shuffleWrite memory is very high and took a long time and still returned errors.
Through some search, I found these might be the out of memory problem.
Following this link [out of memory error Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138751/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space/22742982#22742982)
I  did a repartition up to 1000, still not so helpful.

I set up the SparkConf as

```
     conf = (SparkConf().set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "150g").set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"))
```

My server side memory could be up to 200GB

Do yo have any good idea to do this or point me to related links. Pyspark will be most helpful

Here is the error log from YARN:

```
     Application application_1477088172315_0118 failed 2 times due to
     AM Container for appattempt_1477088172315_0118_000006 exited 
     with exitCode: 10

     For more detailed output, check application tracking page: Then, 
     click on links to logs of each attempt.
     Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
     Container id: container_1477088172315_0118_06_000001
     Exit code: 10
     Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=10:
     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:582)
     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:479)
     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:773)
     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
     at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 10
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Here is the error info from notebook:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o71.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 15.0 (): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 26 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Slave lost
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2086)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1498)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide Hadoop container logs of dead executor? Stdout and stderr will be useful.

Comment: @Mariusz just added the error log from spark UI

Comment: This is yarn log and what about log of executor process? stdout and stderr?

Comment: @Mariusz Now my notebook just stuck there. It happens when I do a df=df1.join(df2), then df.show().. Even I could do df1.show() and df2.show()