# spark heap size error even RAM is 32 GB and JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx8g

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, heap-memory, cloudera-cdh

I have 32 GB of physical memoryand my input file size about 30 MB, I try to submit my spark job in yarn client mode using the below command

```
spark-submit --master yarn --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1 --driver-memory 8g ericsson_xml_parsing_version_6_stage1.py
```

and my executor space is 8g, but get the below error anyone please help me to configure the java heap memory. I read about the --driver-java-options using command line but I don't know how to set java heap space using this option.

Anyone please help me out.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BDWe.png)

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138751/spark-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to configure executor memory as well? 
like this: "--executor-memory 8g"

Comment: yes, I have used the below also, but same error exists. spark-submit --master yarn --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.10:0.4.1 --driver-memory 8g --executor-memory 8gericsson_xml_parsing_version_6_stage1.py

Comment: than maybe indeed you don't have enough space. input file size 30MB does not guarantee that RDDs will not take 1000 times more space.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this issue, Please give ideas to fix it.

Comment: analyze your code (maybe share it here), or try to work with even smaller input file, increase driver/executor memory