# GC error while running spark job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running the following `spark` code and each time it runs out of memory. The data size is not huge but overtime it complains for `GC` error so there are too many objects for `garbage collector` to collect. Selecting few columns and data from a table should not contain much overhead and create too many objects on Heap. Am i creating too many immutable objects by firing a select query. Not sure why it's complaining for `GC` error.

```
object O {  

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {  

val log = LogManager.getRootLogger    
val TGTTBL = "XYZ"  
val outputLocation = "somepath"  
val dql = "select col1, col2, col3 from SOURCETBL where condition"
val appName = "createDFS";
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
.appName(appName)
.enableHiveSupport()
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
.getOrCreate()

 log.warn("Select Query........................")
 log.warn(dql)
 val tblDF = spark.sql(dql)

 def getCols(df: DataFrame): String = {
 val cols = df.columns;
 val colString = cols.map(c => s"$c    


${df.schema(s"$c").dataType}").dropRight(3).mkString(",").replace("Type", "")

 return colString;
 }

 val colString = getCols(tblDF)
 log.warn("Create Table def........................")
 log.warn(colString)
 spark.sql(s"drop table if exists $TGTTBL")
 spark.sql(s"Create external table if not exists $TGTTBL ($colString)" +
        s" partitioned by (col1 string, col2 string, col3 string) stored as orc location \'$outputLocation\'")

 tblDF.write.partitionBy("col1", "col2", ).format("orc").mode("overwrite").save(outputLocation)

}
}


**Error - 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**
```

Comment: Are you running this on local or Cluster? what about memory configurations?

Comment: What about using hive-context??

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22742982/6059889

Comment: @Shankar - I am running on cluster. The data is under 1gb and i am providing enough memory and executors to run the job.

Comment: @RaktotpalBordoloi - what is the advantage of using hive context over hive support in a spark session ?

Comment: @SteffenSchmitz - None of the scenarios described fits my case. I read it earlier. I will try to use hive context but not sure how will it be any different from what i am using.

Comment: I kept getting the above error while trying to read through spark sql. What I did was to read the files as RDDs and then create a DF from it. Not sure why it throws GC error while trying to create DF from Spark sql.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting the above error while trying to read through spark sql. So I created an RDD[Object] from the input files and converted it to dataframe using rdd.toDF() method. This solved my problem.